# Review Suggested Edits

Tags: discussion, support

I don't know if I can I ask this here or not, but I don't know any other place to ask this.

I saw a person review a **Suggested Edit** post in SO with only a total reputation of 119 in SO. He is not a moderator too. This is the [person](https://stackoverflow.com/users/881389/algorytmus).

How is this possible?

Comment: Can send the person's link, if required.

Comment: Post the link in your question :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That was [a suggested edit to his own question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1763003). Any OP of a post can review those.

Comment: My bad I thought it was edits, you were right :). +1

Answer (score 1):

It's probably someone who reviewed an edit to his own post. When someone edit your post you can review it, even though you don't have 2k reputation.

Your vote counts for 3 vote. That means if you reject it, it'll be rejected right away. If you accept it'll be accepted right away.